# Segmentation fault in GC Thread

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, centos7, dropwizard, amazon-linux

We've deployed our Dropwizard service on aws-ec2 with centos7.

We are intermittently facing with segmentation fault on our GC thread.

Currently we are taking thread-pumps every minute to analyze.

Current GC Algo - CMS

**What we tried so far:**

1. Changing OS from Amazon linux to centos7
2. Tried different GC algos - parallel GC, CMS, G1-GC

Please find the stack trace below.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4be96146bb, pid=1016, tid=139963858630400
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_72-b15) (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.72-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6516bb]  CollectedHeap::common_mem_allocate_init(KlassHandle, unsigned long, Thread*)+0x9b
#
# Core dump written. Default location: //core or core.1016
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
Current thread (0x00007f4be40d7800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x00007f4be0034000,0x00007f4be0134000] [id=3424]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x000000010000000b

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f4be9f68c19, RBX=0x00007f4be40d7800, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x00007f4be40d7800
RSP=0x00007f4be0131920, RBP=0x00007f4be0131950, RSI=0x0000000000000003, RDI=0x00000007c00016d0
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x202e64657265746e, R11=0x0000000000000001
R12=0x00000000ffffffff, R13=0x0000000000000003, R14=0x00000007c00016d0, R15=0x0000000010000031
RIP=0x00007f4be96146bb, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
...

JavaThread 0x00007f4adc006800 (nid = 13003) was being processed
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~RuntimeStub::_new_array_nozero_Java
J 3340 C2 java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry; (86 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bb99ea98c [0x00007f4bb99ea2c0+0x6cc]
J 4234 C2 sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource; (97 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bb9cfc970 [0x00007f4bb9cfc8e0+0x90]
J 5849 C2 java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bb9360d7c [0x00007f4bb9360c20+0x15c]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 5043  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bb9e2a563 [0x00007f4bb9e2a500+0x63]
J 5846 C2 java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URL; (87 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bb98f51d4 [0x00007f4bb98f4ee0+0x2f4]
J 26710 C2 javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Object; (317 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbacd220c [0x00007f4bbacd18c0+0x94c]
J 27488 C2 javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance()Ljavax/xml/soap/SAAJMetaFactory; (44 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbab9d3ac [0x00007f4bbab9d380+0x2c]
J 21785 C1 javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/xml/soap/MessageFactory; (8 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbbe04b1c [0x00007f4bbbe04ac0+0x5c]
j  com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.<init>()V+18
j  com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory.createConnection()Ljavax/xml/soap/SOAPConnection;+4
J 24605 C1 com.tp.pg.util.shopping.SoapWSCall.getToken(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;I)Ljava/util/Map; (160 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbc4be4d4 [0x00007f4bbc4be380+0x154]
J 24677 C1 com.tp.pg.util.shopping.SoapWSCall.getTransactionToken(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/util/Map; (452 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbdbd060c [0x00007f4bbdbced80+0x188c]
J 24279 C1 com.tp.pg.util.TransactionRequestBean.getTransactionToken()Ljava/lang/String; (259 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbc40132c [0x00007f4bbc4005e0+0xd4c]
J 27355 C1 com.games24x7.paymentservice.util.TechprocessReconciliationTask.getTechProcessToken(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/lang/String; (321 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbdf815bc [0x00007f4bbdf7f740+0x1e7c]
J 27354 C1 com.games24x7.paymentservice.util.TechprocessReconciliationTask.getReconcilationRequest(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/json/JSONObject; (176 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbb8014f4 [0x00007f4bbb801420+0xd4]
j  com.games24x7.paymentservice.util.TechprocessReconciliationTask.run()V+166
J 16559 C2 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call()Ljava/lang/Object; (14 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbaa327ec [0x00007f4bbaa327a0+0x4c]
J 19385 C2 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V (126 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbcdef074 [0x00007f4bbcdeefc0+0xb4]
J 21343% C2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (225 bytes) @ 0x00007f4bbc1fbc0c [0x00007f4bbc1fb980+0x28c]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
...

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 241217.875 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5932 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 1702K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   2% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1639870, 0x00000006e5710000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e9990000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178323K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 241220.784 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5932 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 547046K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   2% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1639870, 0x00000006e5710000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e9990000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178323K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 241220.794 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5933 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 2633K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   3% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e59a2400, 0x00000006e9990000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e5710000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178400K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 241224.818 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5933 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 547977K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   3% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e59a24a8, 0x00000006e9990000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e5710000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178400K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 241224.828 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5934 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 2257K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   3% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e16c4458, 0x00000006e5710000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e9990000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178467K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 241224.829 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5934 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 8425K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K,   1% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0605fc8, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   3% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e16c4458, 0x00000006e5710000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e9990000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178467K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 241224.836 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5935 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 1601K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   2% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e58a0760, 0x00000006e9990000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e5710000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178572K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 241228.987 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5935 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 546945K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   2% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e58a07a0, 0x00000006e9990000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e5710000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178572K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 241228.995 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5936 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 2411K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   3% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e16eada0, 0x00000006e5710000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e9990000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178609K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 241233.095 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5936 (full 1):
 par new generation   total 613440K, used 547755K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000006e9990000)
  eden space 545344K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e1490000)
  from space 68096K,   3% used [0x00000006e1490000, 0x00000006e16eada0, 0x00000006e5710000)
  to   space 68096K,   0% used [0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e5710000, 0x00000006e9990000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3512768K, used 1178609K [0x00000006e9990000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 75352K, capacity 77390K, committed 77524K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 7885K, capacity 8270K, committed 8296K, reserved 1048576K

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 241213.639 Thread 0x00007f4b60005800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c548d5f8) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241213.641 Thread 0x00007f4b580a5000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c548de20) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241213.797 Thread 0x00007f4b54917800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c64df2a0) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241213.903 Thread 0x00007f4b5c028000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c6bfddb8) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241222.033 Thread 0x00007f4b849e9000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006cccff568) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241226.620 Thread 0x00007f4b849e9000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006cf3d4c60) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241228.641 Thread 0x00007f4b60005800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006de46f1e8) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241228.642 Thread 0x00007f4b580a5000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006de46fa10) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241228.907 Thread 0x00007f4b5c028000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006e0b591b8) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 241230.221 Thread 0x00007f4b787e5000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c9c63328) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u72/5732/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]

Events (10 events):
Event: 241232.882 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint done
Event: 241232.918 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint
Event: 241232.918 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint done
Event: 241232.959 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint
Event: 241232.959 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint done
Event: 241233.007 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint
Event: 241233.007 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint done
Event: 241233.050 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint
Event: 241233.050 loading class javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint done
Event: 241233.094 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation

...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this seg fault constant? If so, can you run it locally and see if it still happens?

Comment: This happens when it's deployed to AWS. Not happening on local.

Comment: which instance type do you use? It could be some architecture limitation on specific instance type

Comment: The JVM is for linux-amd64 - just to double check, you're not running on a Graviton CPU? Have you tried a version of Java higher than 8?

Comment: did u set either `Xmx` or `Xms` ? if so what's the value? also it might be because of setting docker memory limit

Comment: Make sure the stack size is big enough for the thread, which you can control with `-Xss`

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the application need to allocate a large block of memory.

reading [this report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7081933) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747221/what-is-a-tlab-thread-local-allocation-buffer) can help.

usually there is no need to resize `TLAB` size but if you didn't find any solution, try tuning it by either `-XX:TLABSize=N` or `-XX:ResizeTLAB`.

**if you are about to change** `TLAB` size, it is strongly recommended to read [this article](https://alidg.me/blog/2019/6/21/tlab-jvm), and you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893915/how-do-i-decide-on-a-suitable-tlabsize-setting-for-a-java-application)